# Inline edit and update

Tags: jquery

My following code is for dynamic table with inline `edit` and `update` with some controllers.Code is working fine, But I found one error when I do `edit` and `update` operation for single row its working fine.[image]

If I clicked edit button in multiple rows,After that I click update button in any one of the row all rows are updated.[image]Actually related row only should get update right? what is the mistake?any mistake in `each()` method?

here is my functions:

```
function empRoles() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Admin/getRolesList",
        data:'{}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            var roleList = response;
            $('#content').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
                var table = '<tr  id="' + roleList[i].Id + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList[i].name + '</td><td><button  class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button  class="btn update btn-success" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" onclick="deleteRow(this)" data-dismiss="modal" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
                $('#content').append(table);
                editUpdate();
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            noData()
        }
    });
}
function noData() {
    $('.noData').show();
}
function editUpdate() {
    $('.update').hide();
    $('.edit').click(function () {debugger
        var editId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').not(':button').css("background", "#d9edf7").focus();
        $("#" + editId).hide();
        var number = editId.replace("edit", "");
        $("#update" + number).show();

        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)');
        $.each(currentTD, function () {
             $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)

        });
    });

    $('.update').click(function () {debugger
        $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').not(':button').css("background", "none");
        var updateId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + updateId).hide();
        var number = updateId.replace("update", "");
        $("#edit" + number).show();

        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)');
        $.each(currentTD, function () {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
        });

        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        var name = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').html();
        var Roles = { name: name, role_id: id };
        var ajxObj = { oRoles: Roles };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Admin/RoleUpdate",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $(".roleCreated").html("Role Updated successfully!");
                $('.roleCreated').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                     $('.roleCreated').hide();
                 }, 1500);
                empRoles()
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

One more doubt `.focus()` is not working in last `tr`.
Please guys help me clear this.

Comment: Do you have any working fiddle?

Comment: @Nitesh I am getting data from db that is why I din't add fiddle.

Comment: what is the purpose of empRoles function?

Comment: @Nitesh It is used to get data's from db and append to a table.

Comment: What I understood from your code is:
whenever '.update' is clicked, an ajax call happens that further calls 'empRoles()' on success and in empRoles you recreate another table and put it inside #content.
Is this how you want?

Comment: Yes but I am updating based on `id` only right?why update occurs in all rows?The same method am following for `edit`.Its working correctly,Update only is my problem.

Comment: No, there is a difference between update and edit. In 'edit', you are not doing any ajax call or calling 'empRoles()' so no new creation of table happens. Please try once COMMENTING empRoles() calling in update and then check.

Comment: Heh got it .Thank you sooo much.Really you are great!!!!

Comment: Please clear that second doubt also,In Last row `.focus()` is not working.Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are calling 'empRoles()' from 'update' click. Whenever you click 'update', an ajax call happens and then it calls 'empRoles'. Your **this method (empRoles) then recreates entire table and you see a whole new table**.
Please try calling empRoles only when you need to update entire table.